# Es posible superponer imagenes de un canvas en Unity?

Tags: unity

Me gustaria saber si es posible superponer imagenes en Unity, actualmente tengo un proyecto 2D creado en el cual tengo 3 imagenes.

1·Fondo

2.Logo

3.Efecto de destello

Me gustaria hacer que eso efecto de destello tuviera una superposicion que afectara a las otras dos imagenes. Asi es como lo tengo actualmente:
[image: Imagen]

Debería quedar algo asi(Editado con PhotoShop):

[image: Logo Completo]

Si necesitais las capas de imagen para testearlo las publicaré en cuanto me digais, aunque podeis probar con otras imagenes, solo os pido que me dejeis claro si hay alguna forma de hacerlo, y si la hay, me ayudaría mucho el saber como!

Gracias por vuestra atención~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El efecto que quieres conseguir creo que lo puedes hacer poniéndole al la imagen del Effect un material con un shader aditivo (ej. Particles/Additive).

Montando por arriba tu interfaz este es el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió de mucho!

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usas uiimages, el orden en la jerarquía es el orden en el que se renderizan las imágenes, si quieres que el brillo esté encima del background, pero debajo del logo, simplemente en la jerarquía modifica el orden.